# "Failed to instantiate file from module.." error when deploying webpart through module

Tags: 2013

I am trying to deploy a customized Content Editor web part (Just Title, chrome type etc. is customized, otherwise it is just a CEWP) in a farm project which already has lots of things in it.

I have saved an existing web part as dwp, then edited the dwp and wrapped it in a module. My problem is, when I create a Site Collection,using the template that this feature is bound to, it works fine but when I create a sub site under the site collection I get : "Failed to instantiate file  from module  The specified list does not exist. while provisioning web part" error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Key Staff Information" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp" >
    <File Path="KeyStaffInformationWebPart\Key Staff Information.dwp" Url="KeyStaffInformation.dwp" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom Web Parts" />
     </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

- I have tried changing the Type to *Ghostable*, however that does not deploy the web part, can't find it in the gallery.
- I have tried playing around with elements.xml, tried adding RootWebOnly="TRUE", didn't make a difference.

I am doing something silly here? The feature it is in is scoped as Web - could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature should be scoped to `site`

As you are aware Webpart gallery exists at site collection level.

Answer (score 1):

Add the webpart into a "**Site**" scoped feature

This is so that it will create a spdata entry to add your webpart as a safe control into the web.config.

Activate the "**Site Collection Feature**" that you created for the webpart on the target site collection